# Choosing Correct Switching Power IC for 5v 2A Output from 2S Battery

Tags: power, voltage, batteries, voltage-regulator

I am designing a Power Circuitry for a Application that needs to feed 
1x Beaglebone Black (5v), 
1x Device with 600mA (5v),
and 
2x XBeePro Modules (3.3v)

via a 2S (7.4v 1Ah LiPo) Pack.

The Plan of action was to use 1x 5v@3A Switching Regulator to give power to the BeagleBone,  the Other device and an LM1117 which will give 3.3v to the XBees. Is this approach Correct?

While choosing a DC DC Buck Rectifier, of how much importance does the switching frequency play?

Can i use a [MAX16909](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/switching-regulators/MAX16909.html/tb_tab0) for my Application?

Is there any other Switching Regulator for Battery Supplies that i can use? The power source will be a 2S Lipo Battery rated for 1Ah. The MAX16909 takes input from 3.5V to 36V. Should i look for an IC that takes input from 5v-12v for efficiency?

Comment: Just an update.
I found a triple buck switching regulator [TI652510](http://www.ti.com/product/tps652510?qgpn=tps652510) 

JUst curious what the footprint size will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LTC3633 Does the job for +5v and +3.3v Voltage Generation.

What I learnt from enough RnD is Switching Supply for Production Level Designs and Linear Regulation for Development and Testing (Fast Prototyping Environments where u dont need to worry much about Efficiency).

I am looking into doing a digital control for the outputs now via the LTC1157 where the Vcc's of the Modules can be controlled by a digital 3.3v tolerant pin.